# How to install V2X-Hub on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: c++, linux, shell, github, cmake

I am trying to install V2X-Hub following those steps : https://github.com/usdot-fhwa-OPS/V2X-Hub/blob/develop/docs/installation_and_Setup.md

I did the compilation instructions until this one :
« Now, run the following commands from V2X-Hub directory
cd src/v2i-hub
cmake . -DqserverPedestrian_DIR=/usr/local/share/qserverPedestrian/cmake »

And it tells me :
« Cmake Error at CARMACloudPlugin/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find package):
By not providing «Findv2xhubWebAPI.cmake » in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by « v2xhubWebAPI », but Cmake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by « v2xhubWebAPI » with any of the following names:
v2xhubWebAPIConfig.cmake
v2xhubwebapi-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of « v2xhubWebAPI » to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set « v2xhubWebAPI_DIR » to a directory containing one of the above files. If « v2xhubWebAPI » provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed. »

Thanking you in advance for your help i am blocked.

Comment: The last paragraph of the message you posted gives specific instructions. Have you followed these? What was the result?

Comment: I don’t know how to follow the instructions of the last paragraph ( i am a beginner ).